# Google Play pre-launch report screenshots have incorrect orientation

Tags: google-play, google-play-console, android-orientation, device-orientation, prelaunch

My game uses a fixed portrait orientation. I have personally tested on a couple phones and a tablet. I have never seen issues with my code; the game always has a fixed, forced portrait render.

However, all of the screenshots generated in the Google Play pre-launch report show the game rendering in a landscape orientation.

Searches suggest that, by default, the report should have been running in portrait anyways.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842757?hl=en

> Can test devices run tests on apps that use landscape configuration?
>
> The test devices are predefined to run tests on fixed portrait page
> orientation by default. However if your app is locked to landscape,
> you should see videos and screenshots in landscape mode.

Any info is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I did not properly setup my app for portrait only orientations.

I had found a post suggesting the following code was enough to make things work:

```
    Screen.autorotateToLandscapeLeft = false;
    Screen.autorotateToLandscapeRight = false;
    Screen.autorotateToPortraitUpsideDown = true;
    Screen.autorotateToPortrait = true;
```

However, I also had to change a setting in the Unity Editor itself

Project Settings -> Player -> Resolution and Presentation -> Default Orientation -> Portrait

Adding that fixed everything